# Using strstr with 2d array

Tags: c, strstr

I'm programming in C.  I have loaded a 2d array with words.  It is called dictionary[][].  I am trying to use strstr to find out how many of the words have a substring in them of "struct".  Here is the code.  In my function count_matches I try to iterate through dictionary using the strstr function to compare.  It always returns null so I never get to ++matchcount.  Any ideas why?

Here is the function.  inp is "struct" dictionary is the 2d array and n is the number of lines in the array (I.e. how many words are in the array).

```
int count_matches(char *inp, char dictionary[MAX_LINES][MAX_LEN], int n)
{
int matchcount = 0;
int i;

for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (strstr(dictionary[i], inp) !=NULL)
            {
                ++matchcount;
            }
    }
return matchcount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem in the given code snippet.

**Think about the following:**

1. Did you mix up `MAX_LINES` and `MAX_LEN`?
2. Is the `inp` really equal to "struct"?
3. Did you load the dictionary with at least one word that has the substring "struct"?

*Show the code where you make the call to this function if the problem persists.*

**For example, this works fine:**

```
int main()
{
    char dictionary[MAX_LINES][MAX_LEN] = {"hello", "hihello", "bye", "Hello"};
    int output = count_matches("hello", dictionary, 4);
    printf("%d", output); // Output is 2 as expected
    return 0;
}
```

*By the way, you can also consider making the following changes to your code:*

1. `MAX_WORDS` is more readable than `MAX_LINES`
2. You do not necessarily have to write `!= NULL` inside that condition